# Need a regular expression for an Irish phone number

Tags: javascript, php, regex, phone-number

I need to validate an Irish phone number but I don't want to make it too user unfriendly, many people are used to writing there phone number with brackets wrapping their area code followed by 5 to 7 digits for their number, some add spaces between the area code or mobile operator.

The format of Irish landline numbers is an area code of between 1 and 4 digits and a number of between 5 to 8 digits.

e.g.

```
(021) 9876543  
(01)9876543  
01 9876543  
(0402)39385
```

I'm looking for a regular expression for Javascript/PHP.

Comment: "an area code of between 1 and 4 digits". No, the shortest area codes are two digits. Also, all area codes start with `0`, except for special codes, which start with `1`. (`1800` freephone, `1890` local call, `1580` expensive, etc.)

Comment: TRiG, technically, you're right. But with Dublin (01), some people are used to writing simply (1) the same as Cork people write (21) usually because they've added the country code in first +353 1 1234567 I don't want to confuse these people any further than I need to. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work. It should account for appearances of spaces anywhere in phone number.

```
preg_match('|^\s*\(?\s*\d{1,4}\s*\)?\s*[\d\s]{5,10}\s*$|', $phone);
```

People sometimes split phone number part into 2 parts by spaces.

**Update:** if you wish to validate phone number and trim spaces at the same time, you can do it like this:

```
if (preg_match('|^\s*(\(?\s*\d{1,4}\s*\)?\s*[\d\s]{5,10})\s*$|', $phone, $m))
{
    echo $m[1];
}
```

Comment: That's awesome. Almost perfect. Is there anyway to trim the space at the beginning and the end?

Comment: Either use trim($phone) before matching, or put ( and ) after and before first/final \s* in matching string, and then read first matched string. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks mr.b, I'm already trimming on the server side, I just wanted to do it on the client side aswell, I'm using $.trim in jQuery but I also wanted it to fail if the spaces were there. Although, thinkiing about it again, it seems like overkill.

Comment: This answer would not account for a phone number including the international dialing code such as "00353 049 854 4070".

Comment: @TomHalley true, however, it wasn't one of OP's requirements. Here's a modified regex: `^\s*(?:(?:00|\+)[\d]{1,3}\s*)?\(?\s*\d{1,4}\s*\)?\s*[\d\s]{5,10}\s*$`. It would match both +xyz or 00xyz, where xyz is 1-3 digit long country code, so in the end it would match 00353 049 854 4070 and 049 854 4070 and (049) 854 4070 etc..

Answer (score 2):

It may be worth taking a look at the [`Validate_IE`](http://pear.php.net/package/Validate_IE/docs/latest/Validate_IE/Validate_IE.html) class - it contains a [`phoneNumber`](http://pear.php.net/package/Validate_IE/docs/latest/Validate_IE/Validate_IE.html#methodphoneNumber) function which handles a variety of possible Irish phone numbers (with/without area codes, mobile numbers, mobile shortcodes, etc).

Also, if you're working with Irish data, it has a series of additional methods that may one day come in handy for validating everything from Irish bank accounts to driving licence numbers, well worth a look!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=2485

Modified version excluding the area code:

```
\d{3}\s\d{4}
```

Comment: Hi Simon, cheers for the reply, I don't want the country code because I'm handling that seperately and using `/^\(0\)\s\d\s\d{3}\s\d{4}$/` doesn't seem to work the way I want

Answer (score 1):

If it were me, I'd strip spaces and brackets, then verify it's between the minimum and maximum length.